# Excel convert 2d range to 1d range for use in functions

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, user-defined-functions

**Surprisingly, searching Google for answers**, as well as this site, has led to no obvious answer to this problem, so I thought I'd post it.

*I'm trying to create a macro (probably a UDF)* which converts a 2 dimensional cell range (like A1:C3) into a 1 dimensional range (a column or a row like A1:A10). This would be for use in functions such as `MATCH()` when a 2d array is needed e.g. to lookup a specific value in A1:C3. But I would like the function to be versatile so that I can slap it round any 2D array to make it 1D. Like `=INDEX(ARRAYDIMENSION(A1:C1),4)` or `=MATCH("hello",ARRAYDIMENSION(A1:C1),0)`

**I've already come up with a nasty approach**; I slap each column of my array (for `A1:C3` that's `A1:A3`, `B1:B3`, `C1:C3`) underneath eachother in a new sheet (so A2 is copied to A2 of the new sheet, C3 is copied to A9, B1 to A4 etc.)

I then return the reference of my new array (`Sheet2!A1:A9`) so `MATCH()` or `INDEX()` or whatever now looks there instead.

It works but has some obvious flaws; adding a new sheet is time consuming for the macro and ugly, piling the individual columns on top of one another can't be the most efficient method. But in particular, the macro edits the sheet so can't be a UDF (I don't think) meaning I have to employ it as a Worksheet_Calculate Sub which is less self contained than just putting it in whatever formula needs it.

---

I think that's relatively clear, please help/ advise on the best approach, I have only been VBAing for a few weeks so I'm not super slick yet.

Comment: What excactly do you want to do? Are array formulas an optioni?

Comment: The latest releases of Excel for Office 365 include HSTACK and VSTACK functions for stacking the rows/columns of an array into a single vector (e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
Function ArrayDim(rn As Range, dir As Integer)
Dim test() As Variant
Dim rng() As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
rng = rn.Value
ReDim test(1 To UBound(rng, 1) * UBound(rng, 2))
i = 1

If dir = 0 Then
    For r = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(rng, 2)
            test(i) = rng(r, c)
            i = i + 1
        Next c
    Next r
Else
    For c = 1 To UBound(rng, 2)
        For r = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
            test(i) = rng(r, c)
            i = i + 1
        Next r
    Next c
End If

ArrayDim = test
End Function
```

The second criterion is the method by which it is sorted:

0 = row by row
1 = column by column

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Interesting that Excel automatically goes by row then column (at least when there is an equal number of both). I suppose the OP might wish the reverse?

Comment: @SJR adjusted so the OP can decide either method.

Comment: @ Scott Craner - beyond the call of duty sir!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Function OneDimArray(rng As Excel.Range) As Variant()

Dim v() As Variant
Dim b As Boolean
Dim a() As Variant
Dim irow As Integer
Dim icol As Integer
Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("a1:c2")
v = r.Value

ReDim a(0)

For icol = 1 To r.Columns.Count
    For irow = 1 To UBound(v)
        a(UBound(a)) = v(irow, icol)
        ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
    Next irow
Next icol

OneDimArray = a

End Function
```

Comment: You can size the array once instead of resizing each time through the loop: for large ranges that could get expensive...

Comment: I figure you were testing bu I do not see where you use the range that is passed into the function.  Also you can do without the Redim preserve which is memroy heavy, by `Redim A(1 to R.rows.count * r.columns.count)`

Comment: Yes, scott, but I am of the belief that if the user is coding, then can do some of the work themselves, in relation to setting the base of the array, either themselves or how you've done it.  When it's paid for, I do more :)

Comment: I can see your point, but to make a contrary point, we are not only answering for the current OP but those that search later.

Comment: Again, if they are searching.....they are prepared to graft, and again would prompt the question how to base an array at 1, would the other way lead them to think they have to declare arrays in the way (1 to x) maybe :)  Just of the generation with Access/Excel books from back in the day we used to read :)